# Softlayer Got "Connection reset by peer" error when capturing a VM image

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I use the Softlayer python API to automate create a VM and install some packages to the VM, then capture the VM image. The code worked for the last three years. The code runs in a VM inside Softlayer. But I kept getting "Connection reset by peer" during image capturing when running the same code since yesterday. Just wondering if anything has changed in Softlayer that causing it?

> **error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**
>
> 2017-03-31 14:37:03,096 - imaginator.cli-Status - ERROR - Failed |
>   Unknown errors occurred during image building - see log for details.
>
> 2017-03-31 14:37:03,097 - SoftLayer.transports - INFO - POST
>   https://api.service.softlayer.com/xmlrpc/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
>
> 2017-03-31 14:37:03,097 - urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new
>   HTTPS connection (1): api.service.softlayer.com
>
> 2017-03-31 14:37:05,719 - imaginator.provider.softlayer - INFO -
>   Submitted request to destroy instance 30219065

The code I used to capture the image is:

```
transactionInfo = self.client['Virtual_Guest'].createArchiveTransaction(name, disks, groupName, id=server.id)
```

Comment: The code I used to capture the image is like this: transactionInfo = self.client['Virtual_Guest'].createArchiveTransaction(name, disks, groupName, id=server.id)

Answer (score 2):

The code line you are using is correct. The method [createArchiveTransaction()](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createArchiveTransaction) is working as expected, I was able to create an image template using the code example below.

Currently, there are some issues in Softlayer's API server related to **“connection reset by peer”** and SoftLayer is working to resolve them. Some users reported that this is temporal, I suggest to try it again after a while.

Code example:

```
"""
Create image template.

The script creates a standard image template, it makes a call to the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::createArchiveTransaction method
sending the IDs of the disks in the request.
For more information please see below.

Important manual pages:
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createArchiveTransaction
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""
import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual guest ID you want to create a template
virtualGuestId = 29292929
# The name of the image template
groupName = 'my image name'
# An optional note for the image template
note = 'an optional note'

"""
Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device object
containing the disks you want to the image.
In this case we are going take an image template of 2 disks
from the virtual machine.
"""
blockDevices = [
    {
        "id": 45009433,
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device"
    },
    {
        "id": 45009439,
        "complexType": "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device"
    }
]

# Declare a new API service object
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)

try:
    # Creating the transaction for the image template
   response = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest'].createArchiveTransaction(groupName, blockDevices, note, id=virtualGuestId)
    print(response)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    # If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    # error message.
    """
    print("Unable to create the image template. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Regards,